# What's a directive in Dgraph?

Tags: dgraph

For example, in this section of [A Tour of Dgraph](https://tour.dgraph.io/schema/1/)

```
# Define Directives and index

industry: string @index(term) .
boss_of: [uid] .
name: string @index(exact, term) .
works_for: [uid] .
```

Answer (score 1):

Schema directives start with an at-sign (`@`) and can set special behavior for the predicate. In your example, there's the `@index` directive to set the index types like the `exact` or `term` index.

There are also other directives in the schema that you can learn about in the [schema docs](https://docs.dgraph.io/query-language/#schema), such as `@reverse` to set reverse edges and `@lang` to use human-language aware strings.